# Which side would Strax choose in a conflict between Sontarans and the The Doctor?

Tags: doctor-who

Commander Strax has been a companion to Vastra and Jenny for sometime now and has helped The Doctor in many adventures.

The Sontarans a race of clone warriors have for many years been a major enemy of The Doctor.

If the Sontarans were to attack and The Doctor had to stop them would Strax fight with the Doctor, Vastra, Jenny and Clara, betraying The Sontaran empire, or would he instead fight for the Sontarans, betraying his close friends?

Comment: I'd venture to guess that Strax himself doesn't know, so how on earth are we supposed to guess? Unless they write an episode where the Sontarans attack Vastra & company, this is not answerable.

Answer (score 2):

Strax is not the Doctor's or Madam Vastra's friend... he is repaying a debt to the Doctor. It's the same reason he became a nurse (he told Rory that he was quite capable of producing milk for baby Riversong in the Battle of Demons Run).

So on which side he would fight would depend on how important he felt it was to pay his debt as versus fighting with the Sontarans, and whether or not he felt his debt to be paid by that time.

I should imagine though that for a Sontaran it would still be quite a glorious battle to fight against a warrior as competent as another Sontaran so I doubt there'd be a huge moral dilemma there for him. Sontarans don't strike me as having a huge moral compass, despite the importance they put on repayment of debts.

Sontar Hah!

Answer (score 0):

Strax is the only known Sontaran to have spent time with other beings. While Sontarans are more of a shoot now ask questions later type of warrior race I do believe they can have emotions and base decisions off them unlike Daleks.
If an Invasion were to occur with Sonatarans that involved the Paternoster Gang I actually think in opinion of course 
That Strax would be hesitant to fire apon them especially after personally witnessing what The Doctor can do or the revenge he might take plus he is capable of personal care towards others hence a nurse a Dalek would just shoot you for trying to make them care about anything as punishment